# Difference xcode to perform clean and remove the DerivedData?

Tags: ios, xcode

Difference xcode to perform clean and remove the DerivedData?
The more detailed the better.

Answer (score 1):

Clean menu cleans up the directory for all targets by deleting the app and dSYM files with the precompiled headers.

Derived data contains symbol indexes, build products, window layouts of respective app. After deleting DerivedData Xcode has to recreate indexes for your sources, so it becomes slower at times.

Refer this link for detailed explanation : http://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-4-deriveddata-and-cleaning-the-build-directory/